# Proving the convergence of a complex power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-numbers, solution-verification, power-series

I have been studying series' and sequences' recently and I have a hard time really internalizing some of the concepts, so I tackled some problems and I came across the following one, where I am not quite sure my proof works.

Let $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that the following series converges.

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

I tried applying the ratio test, which gave me this:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |\frac{\frac{z^{2(n+1)+1}}{(2(n+1)+1)!}}{\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}|$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |\frac{\frac{z^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)!}}{\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |\frac{z^{2n+3} * (2n+1)!}{z^{2n+1} * (2n+3)!}|$$

$$= \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup |\frac{z^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}| = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup \frac{|z|^2}{(2n+2)(2n+3)}$$

Since $|z|^2$ is just some constant real number the limit of the above will be $0$, which is of course less than $1$ and therefore the series converges. Is this a correct use of the ratio test and would this count as a proof or is there something left to show?

Comment: I've taken the liberty of adding the solution-verification tag.

Comment: Alternatively: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!} \right| \le \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left|\frac{z^{n}}{n!} \right| = e^{|z|} $.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep -- this is a great proof!

(Answering under Community wiki so that the question can be closed as answered.)